# how to tag a HTML meta in keyword?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

[image]

```
    public void FamilykeywordHTML()
    {
        string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["domainName"];
        string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["userName"];
        string passowrd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["passowrd"];
        timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yy h:mm:ss tt").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "");
        client = CoreServiceClientFactory.GetClient();
        string CategoryId = "tcm:13-36761-512";
        CategoryData category = (CategoryData)client.Read(CategoryId, new ReadOptions());
        string[] tcmList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "familykeywordHTMLmeta.txt");
        if (category != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var title in tcmList)
            {
               // string keywordTitle = title;
                string componenttcmid = title.Split('#')[0];
                string keywordTitle = title.Split('#')[1];
                //KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id, new ReadOptions()) as KeywordData;
                var keyword = client.Read(keywordTitle, new ReadOptions()) as KeywordData;
                keyword.MetadataSchema = new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = "tcm:13-145242-8", Title = "KeyWord Meta Schema" };
                keyword.Metadata = "<Metadata xmlns=\"uuid:b001b7a9-0eea-4b27-9795-8d81ea612967\" >"+componenttcmid;
                 keyword = (KeywordData)client.Save(keyword, new ReadOptions()) as KeywordData;
                //client.Save(keyword.Metadata, new ReadOptions());
                Console.Write(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

**Here i need to tag a HTML meta  in field "add componnet link to home page of the keyword"**

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you go over this code repository which describes how to change any content or metadata here: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata.

But to give you an idea, you'd do something similar to this:

```
    // Read the component you want to add
    ComponentData componentData = (ComponentData)client.Read("tcm:xx-xx-16", null);

    // Read the metadata schema
    SchemaData meta = (SchemaData)c.Read("tcm:12-145242-8", new ReadOptions());

    string metadataContent = "<Metadata xmlns=\"" + meta.NamespaceUri + "\">" +
                                  "<metadataField1 xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"" +
                                       "xlink:href=\"" + componentData.Id + "\"" + "xlink:title=\"" + componentData.Title + "\"" + 
                                  "</metadataField1>" + 
                             "</Metadata>"; 
    keyword.Metadata = metadataContent;
```